# Is 'Twisted' strongly pejorative?

Tags: meaning, connotations

Someone said in a comment at [What adjective can be used to describe this kind of behavior?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/341384/what-adjective-can-be-used-to-describe-this-kind-of-behavior#comment655093_341384):

> 'Twisted' is strongly pejorative and comes across like aggrieved complaining.

I was wondering how "strongly pejorative" it is?

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/twist+someone%27s+words says:

> **twist (one's) words**
>
> To alter, distort, or misrepresent the intended meaning of something
> one has said or written.
>
> **twist someone's words (around)**
>
> to restate someone's words inaccurately; to misrepresent what someone
> has said.

Bing says

> **pejorative (adjective)**
>
> expressing contempt or disapproval:

To me, "twist" doesn't carry the connotation of "contempt". "disapproval" and "aggrieved complaining"? Yes, those are what I feel, but not what I expressed by using "twist". What I mean by "twist" is exactly what the first source says.

If it is strongly pejorative, what word would you use instead to  have less or none of that connotation?

Comment: The twisted killer living out his days in a glass box ... YorkshireLive ... 19 Nov 2022 — He's the twisted serial killer who is so dangerous he will have to live out his days sealed in a glass box underneath a Yorkshire prison.

Comment: Priest used church money for his twisted desires

Comment: Seeing Wanda (Antonelli) writhing in fur reawakens his twisted desires. A powerful descent into sadomasochistic degradation

Comment: Albert DeSalvo. The Boston Strangler reveals his twisted motives

Comment: To say that someone is twisting your words is very different from calling a person "twisted". A twisted person is deranged, often a danger to others, or depraved.

Comment: A word can be pejorative in some contexts but not in others. Calling someone "shallow" is insulting; calling a river "shallow" is not. Calling a woman a "bitch" is very rude, calling a female dog a "bitch" won't get you in trouble. You need to focus on a specific context if you want to know if something is pejorative, not assume twist/twisted  has only one meaning or connotation.

Comment: @StuartF - yes, that is trivially true. A twisted rope is fine; a twisted motive not. In _by framing the post in a twisted way_ it is an accusation of dishonesty, bad faith, etc.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Doesn't it nail it, after many occurrences of the kind of behaviors? Every day, there are many complaints on meta.stackexchange.com and the meta board of every SE site. Can you find them? Not easily. Why? They become virtually nonvisible very quickly

Comment: @Tim - alleged occurrences. Not all complaints are justified.

Comment: @Tim - research the use of 'vexatious' in a legal context.

Comment: @Tim: I am having trouble following the discussion. "Does it not nail it?"  What is nailing what?

Answer (score 2):

Twist means:
To *intentionally* alter, distort, or misrepresent the intended meaning of something someone has said or written, particularly in a way that makes it possibly technically true, but conveys conclusions which are false. It can be used as an insult or accusation: "You twisted my words!" or "He is twisting the meaning of our business contract."

"Twist" doesn't carry the connotation of "contempt" per se, but definitely "disapproval." It is not very *strongly* pejorative but is certainly pejorative. It is hard a word you can use that means the same thing that doesn't have the connotation of disapproval. You can try:

"Portraying the words in a manner they were not intended to be portrayed."
"Representing the text in a way that isn't true to the meaning of the text."

To be polite, you may have to use more words in order to prevent connotations of bad faith that come with "misrepresent" and "twist." You may also consider "unintentionally misrepresent," which is possible, but do not try "unintentionally twist," which is not impossible per se but is odd because twist usually comes with an implication that they are doing it on purpose, as it is a negative term, much more so than misrepresent. Twist is semi-informal as well: you wouldn't see it in a court document or press release, but you may see "misrepresent" or even "distort."

Answer (score 1):

Words in English can have different meanings depending on the context in which they are used.  The context is what changes the meaning.  Many words also have literal meanings, but can also be used in figurative senses in different situations, in expressions, or idioms.

To describe a person as "twisted" is strongly pejorative. This meaning is figurative.  It describes a person who has an unpleasantly abnormal/warped/cruel character. It's not a swear word, but if you said it directly towards a person, it would be an insult*.

"Twist" as a verb, ("twisted" as an adjective), also has a literal meaning, to form into a bent, curling, or distorted shape, or to physically turn around.

"Twist" as a verb can also be used figuratively, but is less pejorative because it's not necessarily directed towards a person.  You can say that your words have been twisted, without making any specific accusation.

*Note: Sometimes English speakers will use insults/swear words with friends as a joke. But the situation is that of friends who know each other, and who know it's just a joke, and that we are not being serious.  We generally wouldn't do this with absolute strangers.